# Angular and Stripe integration

Tags: angular, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe into my website but I'm currently walking into some trouble.
I actually have questions

**#1:**
I have followed this [thread](https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/integrating-stripe-elements-with-angular-c2d86efa483) and this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stripe-integration?file=package.json) page. But it is still not working. It looks like my application isn't picking up the Stripe components. [image: payment form of my application]
My ts file

```
import {
 Component,
 AfterViewInit,
 OnDestroy,
 ViewChild,
 ElementRef,
 ChangeDetectorRef
} from '@angular/core';

import  { NgForm } from "@angular/forms"
import { AngularStripeService } from '@fireflysemantics/angular-stripe-service'

@Component({
selector: 'payment',
templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./payment.component.css']
})
export class PaymentComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

@ViewChild('cardInfo', { static: false }) cardInfo: ElementRef;

stripe: any;
loading = false;
confirmation: any;

card: any;
cardHandler = this.onChange.bind(this);
error: any;

constructor(
 private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
 private stripeService:AngularStripeService) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.stripeService.setPublishableKey('pk_test____________').then(
  stripe=> {
    console.log("in function"); // logging to console
    this.stripe = stripe;
    const elements = stripe.elements();    
    this.card = elements.create('card');
    this.card.mount(this.cardInfo.nativeElement); // also tried "#card-info"
    this.card.addEventListener('change', this.cardHandler);
 }).catch((e:any)) => { // no errors
   console.error(e);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.card.removeEventListener('change', this.cardHandler);
 this.card.destroy();
}

onChange( error: any ) {
 if (error) {
  this.error = error.message;
 } else {
  this.error = null;
 }
 this.cd.detectChanges();
}

async onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
 console.log(form)
 const { token, error } = await this.stripe.createToken(this.card);

 if (error) {
  console.log('Error:', error);
 } else {
  console.log('Success!', token);
 }
}
}
```

The application doesn't give any error only when submutting the form i get a error that the form is empty which makes sense.

my package JSON stripe components

```
"@types/stripe-checkout": "^1.0.3",
"@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.20",
"@fireflysemantics/angular-stripe-service": "^1.0.0",
"@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.9.0",
"@types/stripe": "^7.13.24",
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong
I've also tried the CDN version in my head but that doesn't work to

My HTML and CSS is exactly the same as the Stackblitz page

**#2:**
Are there any documents on how to integrate Stripe IDEAL with Angular?

I don't have to solve this tutorial necessary but I need a good working example of Stripe and Angular

Comment: If you're not seeing the Elements card form, then it's not mounting properly - either because that Javascript isn't being called or because there's an error in the console.  There unfortunately isn't official support for Angular, and I'm not really familiar with either of those tutorials.  What kind of debugging have you tried?

Comment: @floatingLomas I've added a piece of debugging code to the mounting code. There are no errors at all en the console.log("in function") is logging to the console.

Comment: @floatingLomas it doesn't have to be this tutorial but I need a clean example that is working a good explanation on how it's done

Answer (score 9):

I found a tutorial that is up to date
[tutorial](https://richnologies.gitbook.io/ngx-stripe/getting-started/setup-application)

Full docs [here](https://richnologies.gitbook.io/ngx-stripe/getting-started/setup-application)

**Create components**

First of all, you should install Stripe through NPM.

```
 npm install ngx-stripe @stripe/stripe-js;
```

Import Stripe like this.

```
import { NgxStripeModule } from 'ngx-stripe';
```

After that now include Stripe in your imports

```
    NgxStripeModule.forRoot('***your-stripe-publishable-key***'),
```

After that you can now use Stripe in your file's
Import Stripe elements in your TS

```
import { StripeService, StripeCardComponent } from 'ngx-stripe';
import { StripeCardElementOptions, StripeElementsOptions } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
```

You can change the styling and languages

```
 cardOptions: StripeCardElementOptions = {
    hidePostalCode: true,
    style: {
      base: {
        iconColor: '#666EE8',
        color: '#31325F',
        fontWeight: '300',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSize: '14px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#CFD7E0',
        },
      },
    },
  };

  elementsOptions: StripeElementsOptions = {
    locale: 'nl',
  };
```

and after that you can initilize a creditcard component

```
<ngx-stripe-card
    [options]="cardOptions"
    [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions"
></ngx-stripe-card>
```

or an ideal component

```
<ngx-stripe-ideal-bank
    [options]="cardOptions"
    [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions"
></ngx-stripe-ideal-bank>
```

**Create payment**

For a payment, you should create a http request to your backend server where the payment is created and handled.
I did it with an ExpressJS server.
First the http request

```
let data = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      postal: postal,
      paymentOption: this.paymentOption,
      products: this.products,
      userEmail: this.email,
    };

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
      .set('Authorization', '*');

    this.http
      .post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/pay', JSON.stringify(data), {
        headers: headers,
      })
```

Now that you've created a http req

```
app.post('/pay', cors(), async function (req, res) {
   const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: price, // watch out in cents
        currency: 'eur',
        receipt_email: email,
        payment_method_types: [method], // card or ideal
        description: `Customer named ${name}`,
    });
)}
```

Send your response back to your front end

```
    res.status(201).json(paymentIntent.client_secret);
```

and confirm the payment

```
this.http
          .post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/pay', JSON.stringify(data), {
            headers: headers,
          }).subscribe(async (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                if (this.paymentOption == 'creditcard') {
                    // confirm creditcard payment
                    this.stripeService
                        .confirmCardPayment(data.toString(), {
                            payment_method: {
                                card: this.card.element,
                                billing_details: {
                                    name: name,
                                },
                            },
                        })
                        .subscribe((result) => {
                            console.log('result', result);
                        });
                } 
                    
            });
```

Comment: its available for anguar 10 v?

Comment: No, ngx-stripe isn't compatible with Angular Ivy.

Comment: I believe ngx-stripe 11.0.0 is compatible with angular 10.